# How to remove extra column in facet_wrap plot with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am trying to generate a facet plot with `facet_wrap` with an unbalanced grouped data, and it provided a plot with extra blank axis column.

Like the paragraph showed, I want to generate a plot without the rightmost axis column.
[image]

Here is an example code:

```r
library(ggplot2)
name <- c(factor(letters[1:4]),factor(LETTERS[1:3]))
room <- rep(c('A','B'),c(4,3))
goal <- c(rnorm(7,mean=60,sd=10))
test <- data.frame(name,goal,room) 
test %>% ggplot(aes(name, goal))+
  facet_wrap(~factor(room))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

'scales="free"' way： automatic set, can it be set manually?
[image]

`facetted_pos_scales` in `ggh4x` developed by @teunbrand sovled the problem, thnaks! Here is the supplementary code:

```
library(ggh4x)

scales <- list(
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100)),
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 80))
)

test %>% ggplot(aes(name, goal))+
  facet_wrap(~factor(room), scales="free")+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  facetted_pos_scales(y=scales)
```

Comment: Use `scales = 'free_x'` in `facet_wrap` i.e `facet_wrap(~factor(room), scales = 'free_x') `

Comment: Thanks! It works well. One more question, how to add y-axis to the right sub-plot and minmum the gap between them？

Comment: You can derive the desired limits from pre-existing limits you can use `scale_y_continuous(limits = function(x){do_something_here})`. Otherwise, you might resort to [a bit of a hack](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/Facets.html#position-scales-1) (disclaimer: I wrote the linked function).

Comment: @teunbrand ，really a hack package, that is what I need! Here is the code
`
library(ggh4x)
scales <- list(
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100)),
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 80))
)

test %>% ggplot(aes(name, goal))+
  facet_wrap(~factor(room), scales="free")+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  facetted_pos_scales(y=scales)
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update on comment of op:**
Does this help: You can use `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 90))`
to set the `ylim`:

```
test %>% ggplot(aes(name, goal))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 100)) +
  facet_wrap(~factor(room), scales="free")
```

Use `scales="free"` instead of `scales="free_x"`

```
library(ggplot2)
name <- c(factor(letters[1:4]),factor(LETTERS[1:3]))
room <- rep(c('A','B'),c(4,3))
goal <- c(rnorm(7,mean=60,sd=10))
test <- data.frame(name,goal,room) 
test %>% ggplot(aes(name, goal))+
  facet_wrap(~factor(room), scales="free")+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But it produce another problem, two sub-plot did not share the same axis length or how to custom the sub-plot axis label? 
Both axis length are 100, or left plot is 100 and right is 80 and so on.

Comment: You can set `scale_y_continuous(limits = your_limits_here)`.

Comment: @teunbrand , I knew it, but it can not work to custom a differnt axis for two plots as I wish.
Eg:  left plot is 100 and right is 80 and so on.

Comment: I am not sure. but please see my edit. with `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 100))` you set individually the `ylim`

Comment: Glad to learn a new way  to set axis, and it works in a 'scale_y_continuous(limits = your_limits_here)' way. Both ways are woked for two sub-plot at the same time(both were set to 90), I am wondering if there are ways to manuly(not automotically set by 'facet_wrap(scales="free")') set the two sub-plot axis in different scale(eg: 90 for y-axis in left plot, 80 for y-axis in right plot).

Comment: maybe `facet_grid_sc` function from `facetscales` package <https://github.com/zeehio/facetscales> is adequate!

Comment: @TarJae , it has a similar function with `facetted_pos_scales` , problem solved!